# App Service Certificate - how to change key vault?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

Due to infrastructure change a need to move my App Service Certificate to different Key Vault.
There is a way to reconfigure it via Powershell or Portal ?

Comment: Do you need another keyvault, or would it be ok with moving the KV to another resource group or location?

Answer (score 2):

You can move an App Service Certificate by issuing a PUT request on the Cert with the new pair of keyVaultId and keyVaultSecretName in the body.

When you do that the certificate will be added in the new KeyVault but you have to manually delete it from the old one.

Take a look at this link to check how to do the request:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/appservicecertificateorders/createorupdatecertificate

[EDIT]
Thanks to MS support, I made it work:

First you need to grant access to your new KeyVault to the certificate service:
You can do that accessing your keyvault and then going to `Access policies`. In there you have to click the hiden `+Add Access Policy`.

When it says Select Principal, look for this ID: `f3c21649-0979-4721-ac85-b0216b2cf413`. At the end it should look like this:
[image]

Then find the ResourceID of the new keyvault. For that you can simply do:
[image]
[image]

Now you need to make the PUT request. If you are not familiar with it, open [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/appservicecertificateorders/createorupdatecertificate#code-try-0) and click in `Try It`. After you log in, select your subscription. This website will handle the authentication for you, but you can also do it from any programming language.

[image]

In there you have to use the "certificate name". That is the name of the resource in the Azure Portal.
Then you need to use this payload:

```
{
    "location": "global",
    "properties": {
        "keyVaultCsmId": "{{the KeyVaultId we extracted previously}}",
        "keyVaultSecretName": "{{new SecretName -> this can be anything you want}}"
    }
}
```

[image]

After doing that you can check the event logs, and the new cert

[image]

Comment: Hi Carlos, thanks for the link. I thisn this could resolve my problem. But the documentation is not clear enough for me. Where I need to enter the "PUT" with the link ?

Comment: This doesn't work for me - if I run it I get a status of 200 but the response shows that keyVaultId and keyVaultServiceName are the same. And I don't see the cert in my secrest of the new key vault. Btw @Mski you can invoke these types of APIs through the green "Try It" button in the snippet at the top of the page

Comment: @AdiUnnithan you are probably not granting access to the new KV to the Certificates Services. I have edited my answer to add more details on that. Miski: I have added some screenshots with a kind of step-by-step. Let me know if any details are missing

Comment: The property for the keyvault id in the payload example is incorrect, it should be `keyVaultId` not `keyVaultCsmId` If you use wrong property, you will get a 200 and nothing is updated, @AdiUnnithan this may be why update not working for you

Answer (score 1):

In order for this thing to work you need PATCH instead of PUT.
So the steps will look like this:

1. Add access policy for f3c21649-0979-4721-ac85-b0216b2cf413 (grant get, list, set and delete on secrets)
2. Go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/appservicecertificateorders/updatecertificate
3. Hit Try it button and login
4. Fill in the form
5. Put the following JSON to the body:
   {
   "location": "global",
   "properties": {
   "keyVaultId": "Key Vault Id",
   "keyVaultSecretName": "Secret Name"
   }
   }
6. Hit Run
7. You should receive HTTP 201 response code. Besides that you should see new Key Vault id in response body.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [ms document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/tutorial-net-create-vault-azure-web-app#configure-the-web-app-to-connect-to-key-vault), if I need my web app to connect to key vault and get secrets, there are two steps. First I need to [assign a key vault access policy](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy-portal), and then I need to modify my code to "new SecretClient" by uri just like --

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string secretName = "mySecret";
        var kvUri = "https://kvName.vault.azure.net/";
        var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());

        var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName);
        Console.WriteLine($"Your secret is '{secret.Value.Value}'.");
    }
```

And according to your description, you have a new Key Vault to store the certificate, so you need to update your code unless you saved the uri in the configuration file. And if you saved it in configuration, you can use kudu(yoursite.scm.azurewebsites.net) to modify the uri.

Another direction to solve your problem is creating the new Key Vault with the same name of the old one, so that the new one and the old one will have the same uri.

Hope it would help. And if I misunderstand your mean, pls provide more information, thank you.